# Relacionar 2 objetos a uma só referência/chave

Tags: java, array, thread, hash

Tenho um `while(true)` que aceita várias conexões (*Socket e ServerSocket*). Cada conexão é passada para um objeto Tratamento que trata sua leitura/escrita de dados. Esse Tratamento é passado para um *Thread* para que possa aceitar conexões e ler/escrever **simultaneamente**.

Queria saber se há alguma maneira de salvar esses 2 objetos (**Tratamento e Thread**) de forma que tenham uma chave só de **identificação**, para quando eu precisar fechá-los, chamar essa chave, receber os 2 objetos e fechá-los individualmente.

Comment: HashMap não resolve seu problema?

Comment: Eu tentei utilizar, porém tenho 2 objetos de classes diferentes. Não sei se o HashMap tem suporte a algo do tipo.

Comment: Na resposta incial eu tinha escrito para você usar dois HaspMaps, um para Tratamento outro pra Thread, porém, ambos indexados com a mesma chave. Essa é outra maneira de fazer, caso você não queira utilizar a sugestão da classe Tuple.

Comment: Eu gostei da resposta anterior. Vou tentar utilizá-la no meu código, obrigado por compartilhar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma classe tupla (para 2 elementos). Como descrito aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12328838/2236741

Com essa classe você tem até mesmo o cálculo do hash levando em consideração os dois objetos. Modifique-o para a sua realidade, se necessário.

Para esse caso ficaria assim:

```
Map<Integer, Tuple<Tratamento,Thread>> objs = new HashMap<Integer, Tuple<Tratamento,Thread>>();
```

Você provavelmente terá que ter algum tipo de objeto que armazena as chaves que ainda não foram fechadas.

Caso mais de uma thread vá acessar o HashMap, então você precisará usar uma versão thread-safe, chamada ConcurrentHashMap.

**Atualização - Exemplo de uso**

Abaixo está um exemplo de como utilizar. Note que utilizei Integer,String no lugar de Tratamento e Thread.

```
    HashMap<Integer, Tuple<Integer,String>> objs = new HashMap<Integer, Tuple<Integer, String>>();
    objs.put(10,new Tuple<Integer, String>(150,"ABC"));
    objs.put(11,new Tuple<Integer, String>(300,"DEF"));

    Tuple<Integer,String> tuple = objs.get(10);

    System.out.println(tuple.x);
    System.out.println(tuple.y);


    tuple = objs.get(11);

    System.out.println(tuple.x);
    System.out.println(tuple.y);
```

Caso você queira, basta mudar os atributos da classe Tuple de x e y para Tratamento e Thread. Porém, sua classe deixará de ser genérica. Caso você precise dela somente para essa parte do seu código, troque para dar clareza.

Comment: Não sabia que tinha `Tuple` no JAVA, conheci recentemente no swift e é muito util, bem lembrado.

Comment: Existem até algumas bibliotecas: http://www.javatuples.org/ ou (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/package-summary.html)

Comment: Como eu posso adicionar os valores ao Map? Estou tentando com `objectName.put(s, Tuple<threadNome, tratamentoNome>());` **s** é uma string que estou utilizando para identificar e **objectName** o nome do Map;

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com um exemplo..